# synchronized an object when possible

Tags: java, synchronized

Is it possible to synchronized a block whenever it detects an object is not null for locking. 
Its some sort of best effort attempt to synchronized.
I can write the code this way but seems a bit verbose:

```
if ( lock_object != null )
{
    synchronized(lock_object) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
else
{
    doSomething();
}
```

Is there a better way of structuring this code?

Comment: Note that your code includes unsynchronized access to `lock_object`, and is therefore not thread-safe!

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill What i meant was that i need a best-effort attempt to synchronized

Comment: What happens if the `lock_object` becomes `null` between the `if` and `synchronized` statements?

Comment: I this case i don't mind it to be running asynchronous mode. Basically i just want the code to try its best to synchronize, if its not able to do so thats fine. My only issue is that my code seems abit verbose and there might be a way to write it in a more effective manner.

Comment: Usually it is not a good idea to synchronize "sometimes". If you have two different use cases for one method where one needs synchronization and the other does not, then better way of doing things is to provide an extra method with synchronization (either on method body or with a dedicated lock object) that calls the unsynchronized method while the code which does not need synchronization calls the unsynched method directly.
Mixing things up usually leads to more mistakes and worse design.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but has no sense. The method `doSomething` reads/writes some data, say, fields of the object the method belongs to. The most evident and reliable way is to declare the method  `doSomething` synchronized, as well as all other methods which can be called from different threads. Synchronized block is used only for optimizations, and novice programmers should avoid using it.

As for the "best effort", best effort in programming means no less than reliable and proven functionality. All other "efforts" are not best, including your code.

Answer (score 0):

as you said :

> synchronized a block whenever it detects an object is not null

I think you'd better use while as :

```
while( lock_object != null ){

    synchronized(lock_object) {
      // your not null activities
    }

}  
// your null activities
```

Comment: Actually what i meant is that i need "best effort" attempt to synchronized